# How to map a list to a certain number of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose i have a list having 10 datas. And inside return i want to limit to show only upto 5 data. How to acheive this.

```
{this.state.PackageCategoryData.map((data) => (
  <div>{data.name}</div>
))}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can slice the array

```
{this.state.PackageCategoryData.slice(0,5).map((data) => (
  <div>{data.name}</div>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to show only 5 items from the array.

```
{this.state.PackageCategoryData.filter((data, index) => (
  if(index < 5) return <div>{data.name}</div>
))}
```